# Trying to write a cypher program in python, I'm half way there

Tags: python, encryption

Here's my code so far.

```
def encryptMessage():
msg = "I came, I saw, I conquered"
i = 0
numChar = len(msg)
while i < numChar:
  print msg[i:i+5]
  i=i+5
```

It returns this;

```
I cam
e, I 
saw, 
I con
quere
d
```

The next part is having the program print the first letter in each line, then the second, then the third and so on. That should look something like this.

`"IesIqd ,a u c wce aI,or m  ne"`

I honestly can't think of a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fix the formatting of your code

Comment: It runs, I'm really not that concerned.

Comment: @JackVanoudenaren: No, it doesn't run; it raises `IndentationError: expected an indented block`.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the point of this exercise is to teach you about the "stride" (aka step) option when slicing.

```
msg = 'I came, I saw, I conquered'

msg[::5]
Out[22]: 'IesIqd'

msg[1::5]
Out[23]: ' ,a u'
```

[More explanation of the syntax here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2581969).  I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: @JackVanoudenaren I did not provide you with "code", I provided you with a tool to solve your problem.  There is no issue with the above, I assure you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> ciphermap = izip_longest(*[msg[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(msg),5)],fillvalue="")
>>> encoded = "".join(["".join(x) for x in ciphermap])
>>> print encoded
IesIqd ,a uc wceaI,orm  ne
```

I think would work

Answer (score -1):

```
def encryptMessage():
    result = []
    msg = "I came, I saw, I conquered"
    result = "".join([msg[k::5] for k in range(5)])
```

You will get output -:

```
"IesIqd ,a u c wce aI,or m ne"
```

You don't need to import any packages, Just do it simple.

Comment: Why explicitly force float division by using 5.0 instead of 5 only to truncate with `int` immediately?

Comment: In fact, what are you even calculating that for in the first place? You want `range(5)` here; it only happens to work because 25<=len<30.

Comment: Also, if you run this code, you don't get that output, you get extra spaces in the middle, because you used " ".join instead of "".join.

Comment: First, it's almost never true in Python that one line is faster than two. Python doesn't interpret a line at a time like AppleSoft BASIC. Second, the performance here is unlikely to ever matter. But most importantly, if you care about performance, doing a float division and then truncating to int will always be slower than just doing an int division. No code at all is always fastest.

Comment: It still only works for messages that are 25-30 characters long, and it still has the extra spaces. And the function returns `None`. Why don't you actually run your code instead of guessing at the output?

Comment: I made correction in my code. Now code is more sophisticated than previous.